# Python urllib is not extracting reader comments from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to extract reader comments from the following page with the code shown below. But the output html *test.html* does not contain any comments from the page. How do I get this information with Python?

http://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/it-doesnt-matter-who-won-the-debate-america-has-already-lost/article32314064/comments/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

req =urllib.request.Request('http://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/it-doesnt-matter-who-won-the-debate-america-has-already-lost/article32314064/comments/')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page, 'html.parser')
f = open('test.html', 'w')
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: The comments are most likely retrieved with js. You can either use a scraping library that incorporates a browser + js runtime (pahtomjs, etc) or try to figure out what the api for pulling in the comments is and use that directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are retrieved using an ajax requests which you can mimic:

[image]

You can see there are numerous parameters but what is below is enough to get a result, I will leave it to you to figure out how you can influence the results:

```
from json import loads
from urllib.request import  urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode

data = {"categoryID":"Production",
    "streamID":"32314064",
    "APIKey":"2_oNjjtSC8Qc250slf83cZSd4sbCzOF4cCiqGIBF8__5dWzOJY_MLAoZvds76cHeQD",
    "callback" :"foo",}
r = urlopen("http://comments.us1.gigya.com/comments.getComments", data=urlencode(data).encode("utf-8"))
json_dcts = loads(r.read().decode("utf-8"))["comments"]

print(json_dcts)
```

That gives you a list of dicts that hold all the comments, upvotes, negvotes etc.. If you wanted to parse the key it is in the url of inside one of th scripts `src='https://cdns.gigya.com/js/socialize.js?apiKey=2_oNjjtSC8Qc250slf83cZSd4sbCzOF4cCiqGIBF8__5dWzOJY_MLAoZvds76cHeQD'`, the  *streamID* is in your original url.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried it and it worked. But I have a few questions:

Comment: First, where did you get the url: http://comments.us1.gigya.com and second, how do you send an ajax query with Python to get all the key value pairs to create the appropriate data dictionary. I don't know anything about ajax queries. Can you please point me to a good source to understand ajax?

Comment: @user7009553, open firebug/chrome tools etc.. look under the network tab under XHR and you can see the requests being made.  ajax -> Asynchronous JavaScript and XML https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started